# Can't find appium ID because all the IDs are showing up as squares

Tags: testing, automated-tests, appium, webdriver-io, appium-ios

Appium is showing all the IDs I'm putting into my code as simple squares. Like, real s.

Tried to start recording myself selecting elements so I could check if the IDs are being actually found or if Appium is just with some issue, but even the code on the recorder displays an  on the xPath.

Output from the recorder:

```
let el3 = await driver.elementByXPath("(//XCUIElementTypeOther[@name=\"\"])[2]");
await el3.click();
```

Fiddle for the output appium displays when I tried to record myself selecting an element:

https://jsfiddle.net/3pLfhdmn/

Running on iOS, Xcode Version 11.3.1 (11C504). My application is built on react-native.

Here's how I'm trying to slip the IDs into the code:

```
<Button
  onPress={() => this.setState({ routeName: GLOBALS.NAVIGATOR.GUIAS_PENDENTES })}
  style={{ marginBottom: 4 }}
  badge
  name="teste"
  testID="teste"
  accessibilityIdentifier="teste"
  vertical
>
  {renderIf(
    this.state.qtdePendencias > 0,
    <Badge style={{ position: "absolute", marginLeft: 16, marginTop: 5 }}>
      <Text>{this.state.qtdePendencias}</Text>
    </Badge>
  )}
  <MaterialCommunityIcons
    name="alert-outline"
    style={{
      fontSize: 30,
      color: this.state.routeName == GLOBALS.NAVIGATOR.GUIAS_PENDENTES
        ? "#308EE7"
        : "#707070"
    }}
  />
</Button>;
```

Comment: Is the front end code written in some character set other than ASCII? It could be that appium does not know what character it is.

Comment: No ASCII characters, it's just that my Xcode was filled up with cache, so the IDs weren't showing up. Solved it by clearing cache, restarted my Mac and now it works just fine. Thanks for the help anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved my own problem.

When you don't add any IDs (testID='testID') to your code, Appium displays the ID as .

I wasn't seeing any IDs because my Xcode was with some cache. Cleaned it, rebooted my Mac and it's now working as it should be.